# How to use DeviceIoControl on a rawinput device handle

Tags: c, winapi, raw-input, deviceiocontrol

So I have a program that is using multiple keyboards as input using raw input and I want to mess with the indicator lights of caps lock, scroll lock, and num lock per keyboard.

So my approach was to `RegisterRawInputDevices` for keyboards using the `RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY` flag. Then when I get a `WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE` message with a `GIDC_ARRIVAL` wParam. I would save off the lParam like `HANDLE hDevice = (HANDLE)Message.lParam;` then later when I get a `WM_INPUT` I can act on the key to mess with the indicator lights using `DeviceIoControl` with the handle in the `RAWINPUT` struct from `GetRawInputData` on the lParam. However `DeviceIoControl` does not like the `header.hDevice` in the `RAWINPUT` struct. How would I use `DeviceIoControl` per keyboard with the raw input handles?

Here is a program that demos the above trying to make the caps lock indicator light per keyboard

```cpp
#ifndef NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX
#endif

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

//windows
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbt.h>
#include <Ntddkbd.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef uint8_t  u8;
typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef int64_t  s64;
typedef float    f32;

#define DEFAULT_SCREEN_WIDTH 1280
#define DEFAULT_SCREEN_HEIGHT 720

#define MINIMUM_SCREEN_WIDTH 300
#define MINIMUM_SCREEN_HEIGHT 300

typedef struct GameState
{
    u8 hwIsRunning;
} GameState;

typedef struct Renderer
{
    //ScreenGraphics State
    u8 hwIsMinimized;

    //Win32 Screen Variables
    u32 dwScreenWidth = DEFAULT_SCREEN_WIDTH;
    u32 dwScreenHeight = DEFAULT_SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    HWND MainWindowHandle;
    const char *szWindowName = "FPS Camera Basic";
} Renderer;

Renderer sRENDERER;
GameState sGAMESTATE;

u32 max( u32 a, u32 b )
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int logWindowsError(const char* msg)
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, dw, MAKELANGID( LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT ), (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL );
    OutputDebugStringA( msg );
    OutputDebugStringA( (LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf );

    LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
    return -1;
}

inline
void CloseProgram()
{
    sGAMESTATE.hwIsRunning = 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK
Win32MainWindowCallback(
    HWND Window,  
    UINT Message,
    WPARAM WParam, 
    LPARAM LParam)
{
    LRESULT Result = 0;
    switch (Message)
    {

    case WM_SYSCHAR:
    break;

    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        u32 dwTempScreenWidth = LOWORD( LParam );
        u32 dwTempScreenHeight = HIWORD( LParam );
        if( WParam == SIZE_MINIMIZED || dwTempScreenWidth == 0 || dwTempScreenHeight == 0 )
        {
            sRENDERER.hwIsMinimized = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sRENDERER.hwIsMinimized = 0;
        }
        sRENDERER.dwScreenWidth =  max( 1, dwTempScreenWidth );
        sRENDERER.dwScreenHeight = max( 1, dwTempScreenHeight );

    }break;


    case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
    {
        LPMINMAXINFO lpMMI = (LPMINMAXINFO)LParam;
        lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = MINIMUM_SCREEN_WIDTH;
        lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = MINIMUM_SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    }break;

    case WM_CLOSE: //when user clicks on the X button on the window
    {
        CloseProgram();
    } break;

    case WM_ACTIVATE:
    {
        switch(WParam)
        {
            //WM_MOUSEACTIVATE 
            case WA_ACTIVE:
            case WA_CLICKACTIVE:
            case WA_INACTIVE:
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    } break;

    default:
        Result = DefWindowProc( Window, Message, WParam, LParam ); //call windows to handle default behavior of things we don't handle
    }

    return Result;
}


inline
void InitRawInput( HWND WindowHandle )
{ 
    RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[2];
    Rid[0].usUsagePage = (USHORT) 0x01; 
    Rid[0].usUsage = (USHORT) 0x02; 
    Rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK|RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY;   //RIDEV_INPUTSINK: If set, this enables the caller to receive the input even when the caller is not in the foreground
    Rid[0].hwndTarget = WindowHandle;

    Rid[1].usUsagePage = (USHORT) 0x01; 
    Rid[1].usUsage = (USHORT) 0x06; 
    Rid[1].dwFlags =  RIDEV_INPUTSINK | RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY | RIDEV_NOLEGACY;   //RIDEV_INPUTSINK: If set, this enables the caller to receive the input even when the caller is not in the foreground
    Rid[1].hwndTarget = WindowHandle;

    RegisterRawInputDevices( Rid, 2, sizeof( Rid[0] ) );

}

inline
void InitWin32Window()
{
    WNDCLASSEX WindowClass;
    WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    WindowClass.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; //https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060601-06/?p=31003
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = Win32MainWindowCallback;
    WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
    WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon( 0, IDI_APPLICATION ); //IDI_APPLICATION: Default application icon, 0 means use a default Icon
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor( 0, IDC_ARROW ); //IDC_ARROW: Standard arrow, 0 means used a predefined Cursor
    WindowClass.hbrBackground = NULL; 
    WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;    // No menu 
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = "WindowTestClass"; //name our class
    WindowClass.hIconSm = NULL; //can also do default Icon here? will NULL be default automatically?

    if ( !RegisterClassEx( &WindowClass ) )
    {
        logWindowsError( "Failed to Register Window Class:\n" );
        sRENDERER.MainWindowHandle = 0;
        return;
    }

    HWND WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx( 0, WindowClass.lpszClassName, sRENDERER.szWindowName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, sRENDERER.dwScreenWidth, sRENDERER.dwScreenHeight, //if fullscreen get monitor width and height
        0, 0, WindowClass.hInstance, NULL );

    if ( !WindowHandle )
    {
        logWindowsError( "Failed to Instantiate Window Class:\n" );
        sRENDERER.MainWindowHandle = 0;
        return;   
    }

    sRENDERER.MainWindowHandle = WindowHandle;
    InitRawInput( sRENDERER.MainWindowHandle  );
}

inline
void InitStartingGameState()
{
    sGAMESTATE.hwIsRunning = 1;
}

u32 dwNumHandles = 0;
typedef struct DoubleHandle
{
    HANDLE hHandle0;
    HANDLE hHandle1;
} DoubleHandle;
DoubleHandle handles[32];

//Use subsystem console when compiling
int main()
{
    InitStartingGameState();

    InitWin32Window();

    if( !sRENDERER.MainWindowHandle )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while( sGAMESTATE.hwIsRunning )
    {
        MSG Message;
        while( PeekMessage( &Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            switch( Message.message )
            {
                case WM_QUIT:
                {
                    CloseProgram();
                    break;
                }
                case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                case WM_SYSKEYUP:
                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                case WM_KEYUP:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE:
                {
                    HANDLE hDevice = (HANDLE)Message.lParam;
                    RID_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo;
                    deviceInfo.cbSize = sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO);
                    u32 dwSize = sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO);
                    GetRawInputDeviceInfo(hDevice,RIDI_DEVICEINFO,&deviceInfo,&dwSize);

                    u32 dwNameSize = 0;
                    u32 res = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, nullptr, &dwNameSize);

                    char *pName = new char[dwNameSize+1];
                    res = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, pName, &dwNameSize);
                    pName[dwNameSize] = 0;

                    switch(Message.wParam)
                    {
                        case GIDC_ARRIVAL:
                        {
                            switch(deviceInfo.dwType)
                            {
                                case RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:
                                {
                                    u32 dwKeyBoard = dwNumHandles++;
                                    handles[dwKeyBoard].hHandle0 = hDevice;
                                } break;
                                default:
                                {

                                } break;
                            }
                            printf("GIDC_ARRIVAL %p %d %s\n",hDevice,deviceInfo.dwType,pName);
                        } break;
                        case GIDC_REMOVAL:
                        {
                            switch(deviceInfo.dwType)
                            {
                                case RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:
                                {

                                } break;
                                default:
                                {

                                } break;
                            }
                            printf("GIDC_REMOVAL %p %d %s\n",hDevice,deviceInfo.dwType,pName);
                        } break;
                        default:
                        {

                        } break;
                    }
                    delete [] pName;
                } break;
                case WM_INPUT:
                {
                    UINT dwSize = sizeof( RAWINPUT );
                    static BYTE lpb[sizeof( RAWINPUT )];

                    GetRawInputData( (HRAWINPUT)Message.lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof( RAWINPUTHEADER ) );
                
                    RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;
                
                    if(raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD )
                    {
                        bool bIsUp = (raw->data.keyboard.Flags & RI_KEY_BREAK) != 0;

                        u32 dwScanCode = raw->data.keyboard.MakeCode;

                        //capslock
                        if( 0x3A == dwScanCode)
                        {
                            for( u32 dwKeyBoard = 0; dwKeyBoard < dwNumHandles; ++dwKeyBoard )
                            {
                                if( hDevice != handles[dwKeyBoard].hHandle0)
                                {
                                    KEYBOARD_INDICATOR_PARAMETERS InputBuffer;    // Input buffer for DeviceIoControl
                                    KEYBOARD_INDICATOR_PARAMETERS OutputBuffer;   // Output buffer for DeviceIoControl
                                    UINT                LedFlagsMask;               
                                    BOOL                Toggle;                         
                                    ULONG               DataLength = sizeof(KEYBOARD_INDICATOR_PARAMETERS);                     
                                    ULONG               ReturnedLength; // Number of bytes returned in output buffer                                
                                    InputBuffer.UnitId = 0;
                                    OutputBuffer.UnitId = 0;

                                    UINT LedFlag = KEYBOARD_CAPS_LOCK_ON;
                                    if (DeviceIoControl(handles[dwKeyBoard].hHandle0, IOCTL_KEYBOARD_QUERY_INDICATORS,
                                                &InputBuffer, DataLength,
                                                &OutputBuffer, DataLength,
                                                &ReturnedLength, NULL))
                                    {
                                        LedFlagsMask = (OutputBuffer.LedFlags & (~LedFlag));
                                        Toggle = (OutputBuffer.LedFlags & LedFlag);
    
    
                                        Toggle ^= 1;
                                        InputBuffer.LedFlags = (LedFlagsMask | (LedFlag * Toggle));
    
                                         DeviceIoControl(handles[dwKeyBoard].hHandle0, IOCTL_KEYBOARD_SET_INDICATORS,
                                                        &InputBuffer, DataLength,
                                                        NULL,   0,  &ReturnedLength, NULL);
    
                                            
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        logWindowsError("failed to get indicators\n");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TranslateMessage( &Message );
                        DispatchMessage( &Message );
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    TranslateMessage( &Message );
                    DispatchMessage( &Message );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }       
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `However DeviceIoControl does not like the header.hDevice in the RAWINPUT struct`? What calls fail, and what does GetLastError() return?

Comment: `header.hDevice` is not a regular device handle that you can use with `DeviceIoControl()`. You can use RawInput handles only with `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()`. `HANDLE` is just an opaque type. Handles from different APIs are not interchangeable. You will have to use the device identification info provided by `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()` to find and open a real `HANDLE` to the device before you can send commands to the device.

Comment: @Luke it returns invalid handle

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok so basically I need to open another handle to "\Device\KeyboardClass[N]" and figure out that N?

Comment: According to the Doc: [DeviceIoControl function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol) To retrieve a handle to the device, you must call the `CreateFile function` with either the name of a device or the name of the driver associated with a device.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT i'm still working on it. One approach I am trying was iterating through the "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\kbdclass\\Enum\\" registry and matching values against GetRawInputDeviceInfo RIDI_DEVICENAME to figure out which driver i need to open. I haven't had time to work on it and i don't have full edge case handling yet. But I feel there is a better way to do it rather than iterating through the registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAWINPUT.header.hDevice` cannot be directly used with `DeviceIoControl`.

You have to do a call to `GetRawInputDeviceInfo` with a `RIDI_DEVICENAME` to obtain device interface path. After that you need to call to `CreateFile` to open this interface and obtain its handle. This handle can be used with `DeviceIoControl`.

Here is some code from [my test repo](https://github.com/DJm00n/RawInputDemo):

```cpp
inline ScopedHandle OpenDeviceInterface(const std::string& deviceInterface, bool readOnly = false)
{
    DWORD desired_access = readOnly ? 0 : (GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ);
    DWORD share_mode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;

    HANDLE handle = ::CreateFileW(utf8::widen(deviceInterface).c_str(), desired_access, share_mode, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    return ScopedHandle(handle);
}

bool RawInputDevice::QueryRawInputDeviceInfo()
{
    DCHECK(IsValidHandle(m_Handle));

    UINT size = 0;

    UINT result = ::GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(m_Handle, RIDI_DEVICENAME, nullptr, &size);
    if (result == static_cast<UINT>(-1))
    {
        //PLOG(ERROR) << "GetRawInputDeviceInfo() failed";
        return false;
    }
    DCHECK_EQ(0u, result);

    std::wstring buffer(size, 0);
    result = ::GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(m_Handle, RIDI_DEVICENAME, buffer.data(), &size);
    if (result == static_cast<UINT>(-1))
    {
        //PLOG(ERROR) << "GetRawInputDeviceInfo() failed";
        return false;
    }
    DCHECK_EQ(size, result);

    m_InterfacePath = utf8::narrow(buffer);

    m_InterfaceHandle = OpenDeviceInterface(m_InterfacePath);

    if (!IsValidHandle(m_InterfaceHandle.get()))
    {
        /* System devices, such as keyboards and mice, cannot be opened in
        read-write mode, because the system takes exclusive control over
        them.  This is to prevent keyloggers.  However, feature reports
        can still be sent and received.  Retry opening the device, but
        without read/write access. */
        m_InterfaceHandle = OpenDeviceInterface(m_InterfacePath, true);
        if (IsValidHandle(m_InterfaceHandle.get()))
            m_IsReadOnlyInterface = true;
    }

    return !m_InterfacePath.empty();
}

bool RawInputDeviceKeyboard::ExtendedKeyboardInfo::QueryInfo(const ScopedHandle& interfaceHandle)
{
    // https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/ntddkbd/ns-ntddkbd-keyboard_extended_attributes

    KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES extended_attributes{ KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES_STRUCT_VERSION_1 };
    DWORD len = 0;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(interfaceHandle.get(), IOCTL_KEYBOARD_QUERY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES, nullptr, 0, &extended_attributes, sizeof(extended_attributes), &len, nullptr))
        return false;

    DCHECK_EQ(len, sizeof(extended_attributes));

    FormFactor = extended_attributes.FormFactor;
    KeyType = extended_attributes.IETFLanguageTagIndex;
    PhysicalLayout = extended_attributes.PhysicalLayout;
    VendorSpecificPhysicalLayout = extended_attributes.VendorSpecificPhysicalLayout;
    IETFLanguageTagIndex = extended_attributes.IETFLanguageTagIndex;
    ImplementedInputAssistControls = extended_attributes.ImplementedInputAssistControls;

    return true;
}
```

> I want to mess with the indicator lights of caps lock, scroll lock, and num lock per keyboard

You cannot open keyboard handle for writing and do a `DeviceIoControl(..., IOCTL_KEYBOARD_SET_INDICATORS, ...)` from a user mode without [some kind of hacks described here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383143/Faking-num-lock-caps-lock-and-scroll-lock-leds). It is undocumented and may break at any time.

Bonus chatter: Windows organizes devices as virtual files almost like Linux doing it under `/dev/` filesystem path. These virtual files cannot be listed via usual APIs. But there is [WinObj tool exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) that uses undocumented APIs and can show the inner workings. It can help to understand how Windows works under the hood.

Comment: thanks! sucks that windows went with the route of global shared keyboard state between all the connected keyboards like caps lock and the indicator lights, and then didn't expose a way without messing down to the drivers to do, making it virtually impossible for user level applications to have multi users with keyboards at a time having all keyboard functionality.

Comment: Yes, Windows stores keyboard state (button state/layout/deadkey state etc) per each Win32 window/thread and syncs it with a keyboard hardware under the hood. There is valid way to switch CapsLock/ScrollLock/NumLock state via SendInput(VK_CAPITAL/VK_SCROLL/VK_NUMLOCK). But it will work for all connected keyboards simultaneously.